# Missing script: gulp error on Windows_NT 6.2.9200

Tags: node.js, gulp

I need to run gulp in windows 8 with this command:

```
npm run gulp
```

But I see the following error in cmd and npm-debug.log after attempting to run that command:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'gulp' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.12
3 info using node@v4.3.2
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: gulp
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:142:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:58:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:345:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:309:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:343:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:113:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:232:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:76:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\UserN\Desktop\App
6 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "gulp"
8 error node v4.3.2
9 error npm  v2.14.12
10 error missing script: gulp
11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
11 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**EDIT:**

gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp-tasks');

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'templatecache']);
```

How do I fix this problem and run gulp without error in my environment?

Comment: Can you share the code in your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a `gulp` script defined in your `package.json`. Any command line command prefixed with `npm run` should be defined in the `scripts` section of the `package.json`. From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

> This runs an arbitrary command from a package's "scripts" object.

You can either define a `gulp` script or you can run `gulp` from the command line:

```
gulp
```

From the [getting started guide](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.0/docs/getting-started.md):

**1. Install gulp globally:**

```
$ npm install --global gulp
```

**2. Install gulp in your project devDependencies:**

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

**3. Create a gulpfile.js at the root of your project:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

**4. Run gulp:**

```
$ gulp
```

Comment: What happens when you run `gulp`?

Comment: when i edit my template, $templatecache not create and write `new` edit template and i see always cache version. i think `gulp` not run and active.